# Angular-Js ng-model not accepting values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

please check this piece of code. I am trying to get the value from UI, but it is coming undefined. It's respective code is as below. When I print the value in console it's coming 'undefined'.

UI Code -

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped container">
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.email"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mobile:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.mobile"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><br/><button ng-click="addUser()" class="btn-panel-big">Add New User</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Controller code -

```
$scope.addUser = function addUser() {
         console.log("["+user.firstName+"]");
         $http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert/'+$scope.user)
            .success(function(data) {
             $scope.users = data;   
             $scope.user="";             
            });
        };
```

Can you please tell what's wrong. I want to store values in a single object and then send it to rest based controller in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $scope.user to get the user object.

```
console.log("[" + $scope.user.firstName + "]");
```

Also it is likely that the following line should be

```
$http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert/', $scope.user)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that, but when I do post below problem is coming in browser. What could be this ?  `/users/insert/[object%20Object] 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: If you want to post the data, use, $http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert/', $scope.user). Notice the , before $scope.user not +

Comment: I am getting (404) not found. when I am using `,` instead of `+`. I am using @PathVariable in the controller to accept the object value.

Comment: What is your server platform?

Comment: its tomcat and spring rest application.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this platform. But you can inspect the network tab in the developer console to make sure if the data posting is working

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized your user object as an empty object?
E.g. var user = {} OR $scope.user = {}

Comment: I did not defined as you mentioned in .js file. But, if I define, I am getting error. What is the difference in both the ways ? With `var user={}` i am getting the same issue. But, with `$scope.user={}`, it is giving some issue.

Comment: Initialising with $scope.user = {}; is what you need to do. What is the error you're getting? The model variables in angular are tied to the controller scope so if you try to use var user = {} there will be no binding between the view and controller.

Comment: @ganeshwani `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` this is coming in the browser when I  click on save option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in setting the scope variable properly.